# download file with submitToRemote

Tags: grails

I'm in a jquery dialog and I would like to download a file that requires a form submission within the dialog.  I would like to use the g:submitToRemote tag to call the download but i'm not sure where to send the data since it's a ajax call.  My current code is below...

GSP...

```
        <g:submitToRemote class="download" controller="thingController" action="downloadInDialog" value="&nbsp;" />
    </div>
</g:form>
```

Controller...

```
def downloadInDialog = {
    def thingInstance = Thing.get(params.id)

    if (thingInstance) {
        def fileResource = thingInstance.fileResource;

        response.setContentType(fileResource.fileType);
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${fileResource.name}")

        response.outputStream << fileResource.toNewInputStream() // Performing a binary stream copy

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use `submitToRemote`? If you just have a regular old form that does a GET request to the download servlet, it should start the file download without redirecting or loading the page in the browser (and thus behave "ajax-y"). If you want I can write up an answer, but I won't if it's outside of the scope of what you're specifically trying to do.

Comment: I agree with rob, you don't need to submit form as an Ajax request to download the file. Just submit the form using submit button.

Comment: That worked and i understand why now.  I'm not sure why i didn't think about doing it this way first.

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as answered.  That way people browsing questions don't waste time clicking this thinking it is unanswered.

Comment: Thanks Gregg!  I'm new on stackoverflow and help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the submitToRemote and used a standard form submit in the jquery dialog and everything worked fine.

Thanks for everyone's help!